# How is the local magnetic moment determined experimentally?

Tags: condensed-matter, magnetic-moment, ferromagnetism

The Anderson model is contrived to explain the existence/nonexistence of local magnetic moments in metallic solutions.

It is said that for a solution of A atoms in B metal, sometimes there are local magnetic moments at A atoms, sometimes not.

How is this determined experimentally?

Is it determined by the magnetic susceptibility $M/H$ vs. temperature $T$? If there is a local moment, $M/H$ is proportional to $1/T$, while if there is no local moment, $M/H$ is a constant, almost independent of $T$? In the latter case, we have Pauli paramagnetism.